How to add tags automatically to AWS Volumes with Terraform
I have the following Terraform script to deploy an EKS cluster (tags left empty to hide values)
EKS.tf

provider "aws" {
  region  = var.region
  profile = var.profile
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      Name          = "Example Eks cluster"
      Owner         = ""
      ChargeCode    = ""
      ProjectId     = ""
      ApplicationId = ""
      #Environment = ""
      PatchGroup = ""
      Eeol       = ""
      Oic        = ""
      GovId      = ""
      CommId     = ""
    }
  }
}

# Filter out local zones, which are not currently supported 
# with managed node groups
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  filter {
    name   = "opt-in-status"
    values = ["opt-in-not-required"]
  }
}

locals {
  cluster_name              = "test-eks-cluster"
  cluster_enabled_log_types = []
}



module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "19.15.3"

  cluster_name    = local.cluster_name
  cluster_version = "1.27"

  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true
  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true

  vpc_id     = ""
  subnet_ids = ["", ""]

  cluster_enabled_log_types = local.cluster_enabled_log_types

  create_cloudwatch_log_group = false

  tags = var.tags


  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    #ami_type = "ami-06d7aa002b2e3009b"
    ami_type = "AL2_x86_64"
    tags     = var.tags


  }

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    one = {
      name = "node-group-1"

      instance_types = ["t3.small"]

      min_size     = 1
      max_size     = 3
      desired_size = 2
      tags         = var.tags
    }
  }
  # access_entries = {

  #}
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "ebs_csi_policy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy"
}

module "irsa-ebs-csi" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-assumable-role-with-oidc"
  version = "4.7.0"

  create_role                   = true
  role_name                     = "AmazonEKSTFEBSCSIRole-${module.eks.cluster_name}"
  provider_url                  = module.eks.oidc_provider
  role_policy_arns              = [data.aws_iam_policy.ebs_csi_policy.arn]
  oidc_fully_qualified_subjects = ["system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"]
  tags                          = var.tags
}

resource "aws_eks_addon" "ebs-csi" {
  cluster_name             = module.eks.cluster_name
  addon_name               = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  addon_version            = "v1.30.0-eksbuild.1"
  service_account_role_arn = module.irsa-ebs-csi.iam_role_arn
  tags = {
    "eks_addon"   = ""
    "terraform"   = ""
    Name          = ""
    Owner         = ""
    ChargeCode    = ""
    ProjectId     = ""
    ApplicationId = ""
    #Environment = ""
    PatchGroup = ""
    Eeol       = ""
    Oic        = ""
    GovId      = ""
    CommId     = ""
  }
}

This Terraform script deploys the cluster with no issues but when I run a kubectl apply -f ./zk.yml
zk.yml:
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Zookeeper
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: confluent
spec:
  replicas: 3
  image:
    application: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.5.0
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.7.0
  dataVolumeCapacity: 10Gi
  logVolumeCapacity: 10Gi

The zookeeper pods get stuck in a Init status because the necessary tags for my organization are not attached to the volumes associated with it.
Error example:
AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-68f45cb0-d06e-4e19-b0ff-c88ecb53f4c8" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not attach volume "vol-0ccc9938279c3a256" to node "i-061ea33a9f07efffb": could not attach volume "vol-0ccc9938279c3a256" to node "i-061ea33a9f07efffb": operation error EC2: AttachVolume, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: a8d8596c-d9b6-4210-9919-bd5ce67f37f0, api error UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. User: arn:aws-us-gov:sts::000451337248:assumed-role/AmazonEKSTFEBSCSIRole-test-eks-cluster/1716299655525948774 is not authorized to perform: ec2:AttachVolume on resource: arn:aws-us-gov:ec2:us-gov-east-1:000451337248:volume/vol-0ccc9938279c3a256 with an explicit deny in a service control policy

To fix this manually I would add the necessary tags to "vol-0ccc9938279c3a256"
Now, I am able to fix this issue from the AWS console by manually adding all the tags to each volume associated with each zookeeper pod, but I need to have this done automatically in my terraform script. I tried adding a "volume_tags" section to out EBS resource, but it doesn't seem like that is there correct place to tag the volumes. How can I add to my Terraform script the volume tags that are needed instead of manually adding them each time?

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

To add standard set of tags to the EBS volume creates by the CSI addon, try:
resource "aws_eks_addon" "ebs-csi" {
  ...
  configuration_values = jsonencode({
    controller = {
      extraVolumeTags = {
        your_company_tag_key = "your_company_tag_value"
        ...
      }
    }
  })
}

